# Tkinter - quit() closes when using if __name__ == '__main__': but not otherwise

Tags: python, tkinter

My Tkinter code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, Button, END
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class InputWindow():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Image Captcha')
        self.root.configure(background='#ffe75c')
        # Initializing the Variables to be defined later
        image_label = Label(self.root)

        # Defining the Input Box and placing it in the window
        self.entry = Entry(self.root, width=10, borderwidth=5, font="Arial 15", justify="center")
        self.entry.grid(row=2, column=0)

        # Removing the contents of the input box.
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
        image_url = kwargs.get('captcha')
        im = Image.open(requests.get(image_url, stream=True, timeout=5).raw)
        image_display = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im, master=self.root)
        # Removing the previous Image (if present) and
        # displaying a new one.
        image_label.grid_forget()
        image_label = Label(self.root, image=image_display)
        image_label.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10)  

        # Defining the submit button
        submit_button = Button(self.root, text="Submit", font="Arial 10", command=lambda: self.get())
        submit_button.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

        self.root.mainloop()   

    def get(self):
        if self.entry.get():
            text = self.entry.get()
            self.root.quit()
            return text
        self.root.quit()
        return False
```

I call this within my function like this:

```
solver = InputWindow(captcha = img_link)
captcha_str = solver.get()
solver.root.destroy()
```

So this works fine, as in it closes when I run using:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

However, when I run it from another function, the window persists and does not close. I want it to close after providing me the entered text. I replaced *quit()* with *destroy()* but I did not succeed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your attention and time.

OZooHA

Comment: Remove `self.root.mainloop()` and place it outside the class.

Comment: I am not sure if I quite understand you. When I commented it out in the class and called it like this _solver = InputWindow(captcha = img_link); solver.root.mainloop();captcha_str = solver.get()_; I got a blank image, defeating the purpose of the entry.

Comment: If you found the solution, post it in an Answer below, not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was adding a line after the **captcha_str** to destroy the window:

```
solver = InputWindow(captcha = img_link)
captcha_str = solver.get()
solver.root.destroy()
```